# Python Dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm using python3.

I have a dictionary

```
simulations = {
    'wk01' : '183',
    'wk02' : '170',
    'wk03' : '184',
}
```

and a separate dictionary containing a descriptive string

```
condition_old = {'slow'}
```

I am later joining **simulations** and **condition_old** to get a complete string.

```
simulations = {simulation : '-'.join([simulations[simulation],condition_old]) for simulation in simulations}
```

This results in output =
`{'wk01': '183-slow', 'wk02': '170-slow', 'wk03': '180-slow'}`

I am then plotting data for each condition (e.g. slow).
What I want to be able to do is to increase the number of values in the conditions e.g.:

```
condition_new = {'slow','med','fast}
```

and return a dictionary for each:
condition01 = `{'wk01': '183-slow', 'wk02': '170-slow', 'wk03': '180-slow'}`
condition02 = `{'wk01': '183-med', 'wk02': '170-med', 'wk03': '180-med'}`
condition03 = `{'wk01': '183-fast', 'wk02': '170-fast', 'wk03': '180-fast'}`

What also needs to be considered is that the number of values in **condition_new** can vary, so I can't explicitly state 3 dictionary names to populate.

Maybe a dictionary within a dictionary would be sufficient.
In the end I want to create 3 separate plots based on condition01 condition02 condition03.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a dictionary of dictionaries yet? Also, why not a list of dictionaries? By the way, `condition_old` is a set, not a dict.

Comment: I am unsure how, i tried to do a few things but because they don't have the same keys it wasn't working.is it better i change condition_old and condition_new to lists?

Comment: cases is undefined in your expression for simulations.

Comment: @DarrylG thanks - i copied from another test. updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a loop and a dictionary comprehension. Something like:

```
simulations = {
    'wk01' : '183',
    'wk02' : '170',
    'wk03' : '184',
}

conditions = {'slow', 'med', 'fast'}

thedicts = dict()
for cond in conditions:
    thedicts[cond] = {k: f'{d}-{cond}' for k, d in simulations.items()}
```

Comment: this looks good - how can i store all three as opposed to printing them though?

Comment: @okpython I edited the answer to put the three resulting dicts into another dict.

Comment: what if i wanted to get 3 separate dictionaries, as opposed to nesting them?

Comment: Not necessarily 
a good idea. See e.g. http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html?m=1